# Remove spacing between CSS3 columns

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get an effect where it looks like:

```
C---------------------------------------)
| Address 1 | Phone Numbers             |
| Address 2 | Times place is open       |
(---------------------------------------)
```

But the spacing with the following makes it

```
(-------------------------------------------)
| Address 1           | Phone Numbers       |
| Address 2           | Times place is open |
(-------------------------------------------)
```

What can I do to fix this?  Below is the relevant CSS and HTML.

```
<footer> 
  <style>
    footer {
      margin-left: 224px;
      margin-top: 1em;
      margin-bottom: 1em;
      clear: both;
      font-size: 0.66em;
    }

    #contactInfo{
      background: #FDF9D3;
      border: 1px solid black;
      -moz-border-radius: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;

      -moz-column-count: 2;
      -moz-column-rule: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
  <div id="contactInfo">
    <span class="address">Address 1</span><br>
    <span class="address">Address 2</span><br>
    <span class="phone">Office: ###-###-####, Fax: ###-###-####</span><br>
    <span id="hours">Open Monday through Friday from 9:00am to 5:30pm</span>
  </div>
  <div id="copyright">Copyright &copy; Business Name goes here, 2010; All rights reserved</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: where are the `address`  and `phone` classes defined?

Comment: They aren't.  Merely they are there if I want to do something special to them.  They don't affect rendering.

Comment: You should probably use a table if you need this type of organization.

Comment: It's not tabular data, so a table would not be semantically correct.

Comment: It doesn't appear that different columns widths are supported by css3 columns (at least according to the W3C: http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-multicol-20090630/#cw).  Not sure there's a solution for this outside of using some other html element (table or floated layout model).  Would love to hear if there is a solution though...

Answer (score 0):

```
#contactInfo{
  background: #FDF9D3;
  border: 1px solid black;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;

  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-rule: 1px solid black;
  -moz-column-width: 200px;
  -moz-column-gap: 20px;
}
span.address{ float:right;)
```

Comment: That centers both columns, and the line is next to both of them, but it needs to be left-aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use some right-padding on the wrapper?
You will need to set a width (2x width column + padding = total desired width).
Remember that you can also change the box model using box-sizing if you are targeting css3 ready browsers.